# bCrypt fetch password from database ( PDO, PHP )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bcrypt

I'm currently switching from md5 to bcrypt and i'm able to set the bcrypt has into the database with the following code.

```
    public function User_Registration($_iPassword, $_iEmail, $_iUsername) {

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername = :username OR _iEmail = :email");
    $sth->execute(array(':username' => $_iUsername, ':email'    => $_iEmail ));

    $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_iD = $row['_iD'];

    if ($sth->rowCount() == 0) {        

        $salt = substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(sha1(microtime(true), true))), 0, 22);   // create a random salt 
        $hash = crypt($_iPassword, '$2a$12$' . $salt);  // hash incoming password - this works on PHP 5.3 and up

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(_iPassword,_iEmail,_iUsername) VALUES ( :hash_pass, :email, :username)");
        $sth->bindValue(":hash_pass", $hash);
        $sth->bindValue(":email", $_iEmail);
        $sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername);
        $sth->execute();

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername = :username");
        $sth->execute(array(':username' => $_iUsername));

        $me = "me";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO friends (friend_one,friend_two,role) VALUES ( :uid, :uid1, :me )");
        $sth->bindValue(":uid",     $row['_iD']);
        $sth->bindValue(":uid1",    $row['_iD']);
        $sth->bindValue(":me",      $me);
        $sth->execute();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but I unable to fetch the data back from the database, I'm currently using the following code to fetch the user login information :

```
    public function User_Login($_iUsername,$_iPassword) {
    $md5_password = crypt($_iPassword);

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername = :username AND _iPassword = :password AND _iStatus='1'");
    $sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername);
    $sth->bindValue(":password", $md5_password);
    $sth->execute();

    if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row['_iD'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way to fetch the hash password back from MySQL.. any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function User_Login($_iUsername, $_iPassword) {
    $sql = "SELECT _iD, _iPassword FROM users WHERE _iUsername = ? AND _iStatus=1";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array($_iUsername));
    $row = $sth->fetch();
    if ($row && crypt($_iPassword, $sth['_iPassword']) == $sth['_iPassword']) {
        return $row['_iD'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect and short.. time to read and understand the meaning of how it worked.

Comment: I find the the only tricky part is `($row && ...` it's to prevent a notice in case $row is empty. So it checking $row first. if it's FALSE, it won't execute the following statement. The rest is pretty obvious to me but feel free to ask on whatever else statement you find unclear

Comment: That was the only part I didn't technically understand, but wouldn't it be better to add else statement with return false after the return row?

Comment: It would be useless. No return means empty return - so the same as FALSE.

Answer (score -1):

**For future support, I have returned the crypted hash with the following code.**

```
    public function User_Login($_iUsername, $_iPassword) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT _iD FROM users WHERE _iUsername = :username AND _iStatus='1'");
    $sth->bindValue(":username", $_iUsername);
    $sth->execute();

    if ($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row['_iD'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $sth = $query->fetch();
    if (crypt($_iPassword, $sth['_iPassword']) == $sth['_iPassword']) {
            header("location:index.php");  
        return $sth;
    }
    return false;
}
```